# Forward custom path logs via rsyslog

Tags: logging, rsyslog, forwarding

I have a mountpoint on my server where logs are getting pushed via application in a log file.
I have created a custom file in /etc/rsyslog.d/xyz.conf.

Below is the configuration of the file.

```
  $ModLoad imfile
  $InputFilePollInterval 10
  $InputFileName /mountpoint/xyz.log
  $InputFileTag xyz-app:
  $InputFileStateFile Stat-xyz-app
  $InputFileSeverity info
  $InputFileFacility local5
  $InputRunFileMonitor
  $InputFilePersistStateInterval 1000
 $ModLoad imudp.so
 $UDPServerRun 514
 *.*     @ServerIP:514
```

Below is my rsyslog.conf file configuration.

```
 local5.*                                                /mountpoint/xyz.log
 $ModLoad imudp.so       
       
 $UDPServerRun 514    
              
 *.*     @ServerIP:514                             #Syslog server IP
```

But still the logs are not getting forwarded.
If anyone could assist me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So i'm not sure i completely understand all of it. Are you using two configuration files? if yes, why?

1. Use one config file for logging locally and forwarding of the logs, which can be done in the standard config file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`
2. `*.*     @ServerIP:514` i hope you edited this.. otherwise i would put your actual ip address in there, e.g. `*.*     @192.168.1.1:514`

**Note:** You are using the deprecated rsyslog config format (which still works). But i still recommend "updating" it. If you're interested, take a look into this [post](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/converting_to_new_format.html)